# How do I save/restore an object's location in the DOM tree?

Tags: jquery, dom

If I have the following html:

```
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li class='draggable'>special</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

How do I save `.draggable`'s current DOM location (generically)?

I plan on dragging this `.draggable` around by by appending it to `document.body` and making the `position: absolute;` but I'll need to restore it if the user fails to do anything with it.

I could do this with clones, hiding the original, and using a proxy for dragging, but I feel like this problem has probably been solved more directly.

Thoughts?

Comment: take a look at jQueryUI draggable, has "revert" option built in

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To save an object's position, you can just save the DOM reference to the sibling before it.  If there is no sibling before it, then save the parent.

```
function saveLocation(element) {
    var loc = {};

    var item = $(element).prev();
    loc.element = element;
    if (item.length) {
        loc.prev = item[0];
    } else {
        loc.parent = $(element).parent()[0];
    }
    return(loc);
}
```

Then, to restore:

```
function restoreLocation(loc) {
    if (loc.parent) {
        $(loc.parent).prepend(loc.element);
    } else {
        $(loc.prev).after(loc.element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi jfriend00, I came across this answer in a Google search and am trying to implement it for a site I'm working on, but am running into some null / undefined variable errors. Would you mind taking a peek at this jsFiddle to see where I might be going wrong in implementation? http://jsfiddle.net/LH9Xu/1/

Comment: @R.J. - see the corrections in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/R43d6/.  You have to save the saved location and you have to pass an element, not a selector.