# jQuery save elements last dom position

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, drag-and-drop, element

I am making a drag and drop system which allows me to move an element and place it next to other elements. Now sometimes I will need to revert the element move after some logic has processed.

```
$(this).draggable({

stop: function() {
    $(this).appendTo(someElement);
}

});
```

How would I then reset the element back to its pre drag position? like

```
$(this).appendTo(previousPosition);
```

How do I get the previous position of the element?

Comment: The following link provides the solution you needed. Please refer to that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492265/how-do-i-save-restore-an-objects-location-in-the-dom-tree